# Autocorrelation for a discrete Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm trying to find the autocorrelation function for a discrete parameter Markov chain, $\{X(k)\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$  with a transition probability matrix given by
$$ P = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} &  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix} $$

and initial-state probabilities 
$\textbf{p}(0) = [\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}]$ and state space $E = \{0,1,2\}$

So the auto-correlation will be given, for $n\ge 1$, by 
$\mathbf{E}[X(k)X(k+n)]$.  However I am not quite sure how to calculate this. 
For something like $\mathbf{E}[X(k)]$ one could use the definition of expectation and get
$\sum_{k=0}^{3}X(k)\mathbf{P}(X(k)=k)$. 
However i am not quite sure how to deal with the product.

Comment: In general, you  would use the law of total expectation and condition on $\{X(k)=i\}$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3\}$. However, this Markov chain is trivial and there is no memory: Every step we independently transition to a new state, equally likely, with no regard to our current state!

Comment: Typo/mistake: The definition of $E[X(k)]=\sum_{k=0}^3 X(k)P[X(k)=k]$ that you give is not correct for at least three reasons. Can you identify some of those reasons?  You should first state a correct equation for $E[X(k)]$ as that is a more basic concept than Markov chains. **It may help if you first state a definition for $E[X(10)]$.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let's see the expectation of the product for $k=1$

$$E[X(0)X(1)]=$$
$$=E[X(1)\mid X(0)=0]P(X(0)=0)+E[X(1)\mid X(0)=1]P(X(0)=1)+E[X(1)\mid ]P(X(0)=2)=$$
$$=\frac13\big(E[X(1)\mid X(0)=0]+E[X(1)\mid X(0)=1]P(X(0)=1)+E[X(1)\mid ]P(X(0)=2)\big).$$

Then 
$$E[X(1)\mid X(0)=0]=P(X(1)=1\mid X(0)=0)+2P(X(1)=2\mid X(0)=0)=\frac13+\frac23=1.$$
$$E[X(1)\mid X(0)=1]=P(X(1)=1\mid X(0)=1)+2P(X(1)=2\mid X(0)=1)=\frac13+\frac23=1,$$
$$E[X(1)\mid X(0)=2]=P(X(1)=1\mid X(0)=2)+2P(X(1)=2\mid X(0)=2)=\frac13+\frac23=1.$$

That is,

$$E[X(0)X(1)]=1.$$

Consider that, for al $m\geq 1$:

$$ P^m = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} &  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix} ^m=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{3} &  \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}. $$

(This can be shown by mathematical induction.)

That is, the $n$-step transition probability matrix is the same as the one step matrix. As a result, at the $k^{\text{th}}$ step the probabilities of the possible states are equal. ($\frac13$)

From here I infer that $$E[X(k)X(k+1)]=1$$ for all $k$.